# Ubuntu 18.04 - do not close on 'close' button just minimize

Tags: gnome, 18.04, gnome-shell, window-manager, minimize

Is it possible to remap the *close* button to minimize a window just like the *minimize* button does?

I would like to keep all three buttons but prevent windows from closing. When the *close* button is clicked I want to minimize it to the dock.

So I am trying to achieve something similar to OS X.

Answer (score 2):

I think that‘s impossible without source code changes to each affected application. It may be possible to hook onto the event management functions of the window management library (X-Windows) to intercept the close button event to change the behaviour of all local applications without recompilation. (That would be a hideous hack though.)

---

However you can hide the close button from the window border purely through configuration if you remove the `close` item from the value tied to the `org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences.button-layout` key: You can use

- the graphical [Dconf Editor](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/dconf-editor) or
- a command-line Dconf/GSettings editor.

  ```sh
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout ':minimize,maximize'
  ```

<sup>[Thanks, pomsky!](/questions/1082742/ubuntu-18-04-do-not-close-on-close-button-just-minimize/1082750?noredirect=1#comment1779690_1082750)</sup>

Comment: Yup, it's possible in GNOME 3, `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout :` does the trick.

Comment: @pomsky: Thanks and acknowledged in my answer!

Comment: @pomsky Thanks! I will leave this question unanswered. Something might pop-up. Something like [AllTray](https://github.com/mbt/alltray)